# Adding &nbsp; to an Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following Ajax.ActionLink:

```
                <@Ajax.ActionLink("&nbsp;", "Results",null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "placeholder", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,HttpMethod = "GET"}, new { @class = "icon-search", id="SearchIcon" })
```

This link shows the actual charachters & n b s p ;   . How can I have an empty action.link, as I'm using font based Icons, and the css and html class add the image and text I need to this link.

I've also just left the link emtpy "" but it just breaks the page.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is char 160, so you can replace it with `((char)160).ToString()` if you like.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(((char)160).ToString(), "Results",null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "placeholder", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,HttpMethod = "GET"}, new { @class = "icon-search", id="SearchIcon" })
```

Of course, you could set this up in your ViewModel with something like:

```
string LinkText = ((char)160).ToString();
```

And then do `@Ajax.ActionLink(LinkText, "Results", ...`

Comment: Ill award you the answer as soon as SO will let me

Comment: No worries and thanks :-) Did you know you can also upvote the answer that you mark as being correct? I saw you have asked a couple of questions where the answer has zero votes. Just trying to help your fellow answerers (and me) gain a little rep :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to use Unicode 160, an easier way is to:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("\u00A0", "Results", null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `" "` like `<@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Res`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `string.Empty or ""` instead of `&nbsp` and set `style:display:block`

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("", "Results",null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "placeholder", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,HttpMethod = "GET"}, new { @class = "icon-search", id="SearchIcon" })
```

Comment: The linkText param cannot be empty or null apparently.

Comment: @Mark, not sure how can i make a use of `@Html.Raw` here